# Set controls on wpf form to readonly or editable

Tags: wpf, tabcontrol

I am writing a data entry application and am having problems dealing with add vs edit vs view 'modes' of the app.

The scenario:  From a window, the user selects items in two combo boxes and then clicks a button.  If the combo box selections don't match an existing record, the form should open with a new record ready to have values inserted.  If the selections DO match an existing record, this record should be opened with all the textboxes in the form in 'Readonly' mode.  Should the user wish to modify the existing data, they click the form's Edit button which sets the textboxes as 'Editable'.

I'm new to wpf, but in my vba apps, I'd normally have a DataMode property and a ToggleControls method which would loop through the TabControl's TabItems and then loop through the TabItems' controls, setting the IsReadOnly property of any TextBox controls found based on the 'DataMode' property.  However, I have doubts about whether this is the path to follow in wpf.

So, my question is, do i use the approach above?  If so, how do I access the controls in a TabItem.  This doesn't work: `foreach (Control ctrl in MyTabCtrl) { //if Textbox do stuff }`.

If this isn't the way to do it, can someone show me the way?  I'm guessing it's either a template / style issue or something to do with setting the data as readonly somehow, and then binding the TextBox's IsReadOnly property to the state of the data. Edit: Oh, or that ViewStateManager thing.  All of which i know little about.

Comment: @oliver-vogel I tried the suggested answer but it isn't working.  In the output I see a lot of the following errors:
`System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'IsReadOnly' property not found on 'object' ''ListCollectionView' (HashCode=61470971)'. BindingExpression:Path=IsReadOnly; DataItem='ListCollectionView' (HashCode=61470971); target element is 'TextBox' (Name=''); target property is 'IsReadOnly' (type 'Boolean')`
Can you please show me how I can progress further?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easy approach would be

**In Code behind declare a DependencyProperty named `IsReadOnly`**

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty IsReadOnlyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            "IsReadOnly",
            typeof (bool),
            typeof (MainWindow)
            );

        public bool IsReadOnly
        {
            get { return (bool) GetValue(IsReadOnlyProperty); }
            set { SetValue(IsReadOnlyProperty, value); }
        }
```

**Implement the Buttons Click event, so that IsReadOnly gets `false` on Click**

```
 private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        IsReadOnly = false;
    }
```

**Bind the TextBoxes to the `IsReadonly` property using `DataBinding`**

```
   <TextBox IsReadOnly="{Binding Path=IsReadOnly, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}, Mode=OneWay}" />
```

This binding assumes that your code behind is not your `DataContext` and you therefore have to bind relatively to the Window/ UserControl which the CodeBehind is applied to.

This way the TextBoxes listen to changes on this property. When it switches, they change their ReadOnly state automatically.

Comment: Adding to what @Oliver suggested we can add this binding into the default base `Style` of `TextBox` in the `Window.Resources` so that it automatically applies to all the textboxes on your form the moment you set the `IsReadOnly` flag to true at `Window` level. This way you avoid the overhead to set the binding explicitly at each textbox in your form.

Comment: thanks for this ... looking up DependencyProperties as we speak <strikeout>feel free to point to any code that might be floating around ... </strikeout>  Oh, you did   :-)

Comment: >>This binding assumes that your code behind is not your DataContext and you therefore have to bind relatively to the Window/UserControl which the CodeBehind is applied to.
Umm, I have an edmx file for my data.  Is this the same as DataContext?  if so, my CodeBehind is not my datacontext.  

The suggestion doesn't seem to be working.  Is there a way of looking under the hood to see what's happening incorrectly?

Comment: Hi Oliver,  I've followed the steps for a couple of individual TextBoxes to test - but it doesn't seem to be working.  The property is being set correctly, but I can still make (and save) changes in the TextBox.  Should it happen automatically or do I need a ToggleControls method still?

Comment: The ReadOnly Mode should be set automatically on the Textbox if its state switches. You could try setting the Binding's UpdateSourceTrigger to UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged. Additionally try to inspect the VisualStudio's Output Window for any Binding Errors which may have occured.

Comment: @oliver: There are errors, I listed them as a response to the OP.  A lot of `BindingExpression path error: 'IsReadOnly' property not found on 'object' ''ListCollectionView'` errors.
The Editor Window says "Property 'UpdateSourceTrigger' was not found in type 'TextBox'.

Comment: OK, found the problem.  My code is taking place in a different window than MainWindow.  I had to change the name of the 3rd property in the DependencyProperty constructor to the name of my window and it all worked.   Asked and Answered

Answer (score -1):

You can use DataContext :

Bind the datacontext of your tabControl to your record (with the button event click write 
this.Canvas.DataContext = _yourRecord for sample)

```
public void bntEvent_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Do matching and put the result in result field 
        MyTabCtrl.DataContext = false;
    }
```

Bind IsReadOnly/IsEnable property of your textboxs on your datacontext and use a converter to return true/false value

```
    <TextBox IsReadOnly="{Binding .}" />
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx for more informations about Converters.

I hope I help you and you understand my bad English.

Good bye